# Trouble understanding Vectors, my object gets stuck after a few iterations

Tags: java, vector, processing

Im trying to write a class that draws a square shape with 4 vertexes. I want each vertex to have its own velocity and path for each iteration in the drawloop. It seems to work for a few iterations until it gets "stuck" and Im having trouble understanding why that is.  Any help or information regarding this is helpful, I suspect I dont have a full grasp of using vectors properly.[Heres an image of when the code is running.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ob1nK.png)

```
void draw() {

  p.display();


  //Stop loop setting
  if (loop == 0) {
    noLoop();
  }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------//


class Pillar
{
  PVector v1Velocity,v2Velocity,v3Velocity,v4Velocity,
          v1Pos,v2Pos,v3Pos,v4Pos,
          v1End,v2End,v3End,v4End,
          v1Acceleration,v2Acceleration,v3Acceleration,v4Acceleration,
          origin;
  float life,scale,randDegrees1,randDegrees2,randDegrees3,randDegrees4,maxVelocity;

  Pillar (float _x, float _y, float _scale) {
    scale = _scale; // scale of pillar
    origin = new PVector(_x,_y); //pillar point of origin
    v1Pos = new PVector(origin.x-(scale*1.5),origin.y); //vertex 1 start left
    v2Pos = new PVector(origin.x,origin.y-scale); //vertex 2 start top
    v3Pos = new PVector(origin.x+(scale*1.5),origin.y); //vertex 3 start right
    v4Pos = new PVector(origin.x,origin.y+scale); //vertex 4 start bottom

    v1End = new PVector(origin.x+random(50,200),origin.y-random(50,200));
    v2End = new PVector(origin.x+random(50,200),origin.y-random(50,200));
    v3End = new PVector(origin.x+random(50,200),origin.y-random(50,200));
    v4End = new PVector(origin.x+random(50,200),origin.y-random(50,200));

    randDegrees1 = random(360);
    randDegrees2 = random(360);
    randDegrees3 = random(360);
    randDegrees4 = random(360);//Fixa denna.

    v1Velocity = new PVector(cos(radians(randDegrees1)),sin(radians(randDegrees1)));
    v2Velocity = new PVector(cos(radians(randDegrees2)),sin(radians(randDegrees2)));
    v3Velocity = new PVector(cos(radians(randDegrees3)),sin(radians(randDegrees3)));
    v4Velocity = new PVector(cos(radians(randDegrees4)),sin(radians(randDegrees4)));
    maxVelocity = 5;

    life = 100;

  }


  void calculateVector() {




    v1Acceleration = PVector.sub(v1End,v1Pos);
    v1Velocity.add(v1Acceleration);

    v2Acceleration = PVector.sub(v2End,v2Pos);
    v2Velocity.add(v2Acceleration);

    v3Acceleration = PVector.sub(v3End,v3Pos);
    v3Velocity.add(v3Acceleration);

    v4Acceleration = PVector.sub(v4End,v4Pos);
    v4Velocity.add(v4Acceleration);

    v1Acceleration.setMag(life);
    v2Acceleration.setMag(life);
    v3Acceleration.setMag(life);
    v4Acceleration.setMag(life);

    v1Velocity.limit(maxVelocity);
    v2Velocity.limit(maxVelocity);
    v3Velocity.limit(maxVelocity);
    v4Velocity.limit(maxVelocity);

    v1Pos.add(v1Velocity);
    v2Pos.add(v2Velocity);
    v3Pos.add(v3Velocity);
    v4Pos.add(v4Velocity);

    life -= 1;


  }

  void display () {
    beginShape();
    stroke(0,0,0,50);
    vertex(v1Pos.x,v1Pos.y);
    vertex(v2Pos.x,v2Pos.y);
    vertex(v3Pos.x,v3Pos.y);
    vertex(v4Pos.x,v4Pos.y);
    endShape(CLOSE);
    calculateVector();


  }






}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that we can actually run. For example, you haven't provided the `p` variable or the `loop` variable.

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to do, but from your code it seems that this is natural behaviour. You set (random) initial positions once in the constructor for the four vectors (v1Pos, v2Pos etc.) and end ones as well (v1End, v2End etc.) and then continuously calculate the difference from initial to end (you call this v1Acceleration etc.) which you then use to push the vectors towards. When the vPos bypass the vEnd they return back and thus the only thing they can do is go back and forth over them. The only way they can move again is if you change the vEnds

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful comments! Your advice put me in the right direction, Petros! 
I'll include more complete code examples next time Kevin! Thank you!

I've decided to rewrite this and look for a more efficient and smarter way to deal with the endpoint vectors / behavior of the shape.